# ZK with Websphere Application Server - Timeout on any Event

Tags: jpa, ejb, websphere, zk

I have started working with ZK recently. I really like the framework but I am having a lot of problems in configuring it to work correctly with Websphere Application Server v8.0. Namely, I am developing an EJB application with accessing the database via JPA entities and using the ZK framework for GUI. I am developing the application using the Rational Software Architect 8.5.

When I start working on a fresh ZK project in a fresh workspace and server profile everything seems to be working correctly. However, after some time I start having strange problems. I think the problem occurs in the moment when ZK tries to initialize my ViewModel class. I do not get any exceptions or errors, but get the timeout message  in my browser: "The page or component you request is no longer available. This is normally caused by timeout, opening too many Web pages, or rebooting
the server."

My ViewModel initializes by resolving the EJB bean I am using for business logic. That normally works, but as I said, after working for some time on the project, or after restarting my computer the ViewModel object cannot get initialized and the timeout error appears no matter what I do (when ZK tries to bind a variable or when I fire an event needed to be handled by my ViewModel. As before, I do not get any additional errors or exceptions.

Has anybody already had this problem? Is there a solution? Can I change the configuration of my server or ZK to avoid this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I have solved the problem myself. I was using internal Rational Software Architect (Eclipse) browser which apparently has problems handling ZK sessions. When I switched to Firefox, the problems I explained stopped appearing.